# Cannot fill the WTForm properly with request.args

Tags: python, json, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to fill the form through WTForms:

```
class SearchForm(Form):
    dt1 = DateTimeField(validators=[validators.Required()])
    dt2 = DateTimeField(validators=[validators.Required()])
    count  = IntegerField(default=10, validators=[validators.Optional()])
    offset  = IntegerField(default=0, validators=[validators.Optional()])

@app.route('/rest-api/get_calls/<phone_number>', methods=['GET'])
def get_calls(phone_number):
    form = SearchForm(request.args)
```

The request is like that:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Oct/2016 23:23:19] "GET /rest-api/get_calls/003223185901?dt1=2016-01-01T00:00:00&dt2=2016-08-31T00:00:00 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

but I get this:

```
{'dt2': ['This field is required.'], 'dt1': ['This field is required.']}
```

It looks like request.args is not working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing the date/time values in the right format.  `DateTimeField` expects `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` but you've passed `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S`, notice the `T`.  Either pass the expected format or change it with `DateTimeField(format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S', ...)`.